# Another awk(ward) question - mapping substrings with multi-keys

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk, gawk

I have two files that look like this:

`mapping.txt`:

```
100178  L08/2015
100180  L08/2015
103822  J03/2012
103823  A06/2012
103823  J02/2012
103823  J03/2012
...
```

`input.txt`:

```
100180011|225|
100180011|226|
100181111|201|
100181111|202|
103823004|011|
103823004|012|
...
```

Desired `output.txt` wherein if the first 6-digits of the input file match one or more entries from the mapping file, output the third column as the second column of the mapping file, else put "B00/0000":

```
100180011|225|L08/2015
100180011|226|L08/2015  
100181111|201|B00/0000
100181111|202|B00/0000
103823004|011|A06/2012
103823004|011|J02/2012
103823004|011|J03/2012
103823004|012|A06/2012
103823004|012|J02/2012
103823004|012|J03/2012
```

Ideally, this should work on OSX, but I also have access to a Linux box.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `bash`, and also assuming both files are sorted:

```
join -a1 <(sed 's/./& /6' input.txt) mapping.txt | sed 's/ //g; s/|$/|B00\/0000/'
```

Output:

```
100180011|225|L08/2015
100180011|226|L08/2015
100181111|201|B00/0000
100181111|202|B00/0000
103823004|011|A06/2012
103823004|011|J02/2012
103823004|011|J03/2012
103823004|012|A06/2012
103823004|012|J02/2012
103823004|012|J03/2012
```

No `awk` in sight, sorry. :)

**Edit:** explanation:

- `sed 's/./& /6'` - adds a space after the 6th character on each line, so the output is `100180 011|225|L08/2015`
- `join -a1` joins the files on the first column; `-a1` tells `join` to leave unchanged unmatched lines from the first file
- `sed 's/ //g;'` - remove the spaces in the result
- ... `'s/|$/|B00\/0000/'` - adds `/|B00/0000` to the lines ending with `|`, that is, to the unmatched lines from the first file.

Comment: The `bash` assumption isn't necessary: `sed 's/./& /6' input.txt | join -a1 - mapping.txt | sed 's/ //g; s/|$/|B00\/0000/'`

Comment: Could you help me understand this part of sed - /|$/

Answer (score 2):

You can try following `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { k = substr($1, 1, 6); x[$1,$2] = k; y[$1,$2] = 0; next; } { for (i in x) { if (x[i] == $1) { split(i, t, SUBSEP); print t[1] "|" t[2] "|" $2; y[i] = 1; } } } END { for (i in y) if (y[i] == 0) { split(i, t, SUBSEP); print t[1] "|" t[2] "|B00/0000" } }' FS="|" input.txt FS=" " mapping.txt
```

Result should be:

```
100180011|225|L08/2015
100180011|226|L08/2015
103823004|011|A06/2012
103823004|012|A06/2012
103823004|011|J02/2012
103823004|012|J02/2012
103823004|011|J03/2012
103823004|012|J03/2012
100181111|201|B00/0000
100181111|202|B00/0000
```

Comment: Thanks @taliezin, the solution works well, but I have to admit that it's woefully slow ;)!

Comment: The other solution is probably what you are looking for. :)

Comment: Damn! You're a good sport!

Comment: @mikeserv, thanks but this is obvious. :)